# Is there a way to get notified right before DOM node is going to be mutated?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

As you might know, there is a very handy [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that can notify us after there have been changes to the DOM node (e.g. the child elements have been reordered or removed)

I'm looking for a way to also get notified right *before* such changes are about to happen.

Does something like that exist?...

Comment: The one way I can think of notifying *before* would be to have an event listener sitting on the function that will modify the DOM, it will dispatch `starting-edit` event before your next function invocation and you will have time to process whatever you need.

Comment: There's no such thing in DOM but depending on your use case you can intercept the most common methods like Node.prototype.appendChild and a dozen of others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help exactly, but this is something similar to what I meant in the comments.

You can read about creating custom triggers and events [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

You can make it more general, this is just a quick mock-up:

---

```js
let beforeChangeEvent = new Event('beforechange');
let delay = 1000; // 1 second

function attachChangeEvents() {
  let ul = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  ul.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('beforechange', e => {
      console.log(e.target.textContent + " is about to change.")
    });
  });
}

function simulateModifyNode() {
  let ul = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let liCount = ul.length;
  let randomLi = Math.floor(Math.random() * liCount);
  ul[randomLi].dispatchEvent(beforeChangeEvent);
  setTimeout(() => {
    ul[randomLi].style.color = 'red';
  }, delay);
}

attachChangeEvents();

simulateModifyNode();
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Node 1</li>
    <li>Node 2</li>
    <li>Node 3</li>
    <li>Node 4</li>
    <li>Node 5</li>
    <li>Node 6</li>
    <li>Node 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't help, because the whole point is that I do not have control of the code the initiates the change.
--
If I did, I wouldn't need MutationObserver either because I could just similarly invoke a callback after the change.
--
Libraries like react are awesome by the way for providing lifecycle hooks like `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` before mutating the DOM. But I hope to find a framework-agnostic solution.

Comment: Okay! Will keep that in mind. I'm curious myself about what solution you come with, so do come back and let us know! :)

Comment: Sure! But currently the best solution I can think of is just to ask for the user of the library to call a method before making changes. Another one would be to "undo" the mutations in the mutation observer callback, read the data that I need and "redo" them again. But this is awfully hacky so I wish it won't come to this :)